# Android: Creating an animation delay without startOffset?

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, delay

So I have just started to develop an app for android in android studio but am in a bit of a dilemma, I have created a few XML animations to use in my application and one of them has the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:startOffset="15000"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    />
</set>
```

This XML animation (swipetext_animation_flash) is being used on a TextView (SwipeText) and is supposed to wait 15 seconds before starting and then fade in and out infinitely, however it is not doing this.

Instead it is waiting 15 seconds, fading on to the screen and then waiting much longer than 1 second to fade off. I think this is because of the startOffset attribute but I can't remove it because I am not sure in what other ways I can delay the animation.

This is the code that is in the corresponding java file:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Loading_Menu extends AppCompatActivity {

public Animation animation;
public ImageView Logo;
public TextView Heading, SubHeading, SwipeText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loading__menu);

    Logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Logo);
    animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.logo_animation_in);
    Logo.startAnimation(animation);

    Heading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Heading);
    animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.introheader_animation_in);
    Heading.startAnimation(animation);

    SubHeading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SubHeading);
    animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.subheaderintro_animation_in);
    SubHeading.startAnimation(animation);

    SwipeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SwipeText);
    animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.swipetext_animation_flash);
    SwipeText.startAnimation(animation);

  }
}
```

This class runs how I want it to, however it is just getting the SwipeText animation to run how I want it to which is the problem.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

android:startOffset will apply for every Animation repetition, every animation repetition with delay 15 seconds. Instead of using android:startOffset we will start animation after 15 seconds after that Animation will repeat every 1 second.

Please try below mentioned code.

```
public class AnimActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private Animation mAnimation;
        private ImageView mLogo;
        private TextView mHeading;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_anim);
        mAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.anim);
        mLogo = findViewById(R.id.logo);
        mHeading = findViewById(R.id.heading);
        startAnim();
    }

    private void startAnim() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mLogo.startAnimation(mAnimation);
                mHeading.startAnimation(mAnimation);
            }
        }, 15000);
    }
}
```

anim.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```